# fonts to html output Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

When I used \textsf{what} in the following document, "what" disappears in the output file. What should I do to prevent the problem while changing the font of "what"? Thanks!

```
title: "test"
author: test 
date: 11/23/2020
link-citations: yes
output:
  bookdown::html_document2: default
---

\textsf{what}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the font when rendering to html output you colud use some inline CSS e.g.

`<p style = "font-family: Times New Roman; color: red;">what</p>`

will print "what" in `red` using `Times New Roman`.

Comment: I used a lot of \textsf in a document originally developed for pdf. Is there a short way to replace \textsf using CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `\textsf{what}` is latex syntax, which is for PDF output. You are rendering to HTML in your example.

as the @stefan suggested inline CSS in your Rmarkdown it would look like this

```
---
title: "test"
author: test 
date: 11/23/2020
link-citations: yes
output:
  bookdown::html_document2: default
---


<style>
body, p {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black; 
  font-family: Arial Black;
}
</style>

what
```

I used `Arial Black` for the example to showcase the effects below.

[image]